# Which API is used for getting Invoice and Label for Amazon orders using Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-mws

I am making an application that accesses the orders programmatically using Amazon MWS API. I want to get the invoice and label for order but I don't know which API is providing this facility, as I checked Merchant Fulfillment API but that is available only in the US,UK, and Germany and I am confused that is the API I am looking for.

Please suggest me which API is suited for this and also what is the difference between Inbound and outbound shipment API provided by Amazon MWS.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Praveen I don't think there is any API to get the invoice, but maybe the Amazon Finances API's ListFinancialEvents api call using amazon orderID might give you the something similar but still I am not sure.

Comment: @Keyur thanks for reply but also i didn't found the label generation request or response parameter on that API as well.

Comment: I had read on API´s guide (http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_ES/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_Datatypes.html) that "Invoice information (available only in China)."